# Code failing when trying to save an image to the external storage

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to save an image that was taken through invoking the camera intent to my external storage, however, the app crashes after asking for the camera permissions

**Test.java**

```
    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            invokeCamera();
        } else {
            String [] permissionRequest = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permissionRequest, CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                invokeCamera();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot use camera without permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void invokeCamera() {
        Uri pictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", createImageFile());

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, pictureUri);
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(takePictureIntent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private File createImageFile() {
        File picturesDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String timeStamp = sdf.format(new Date());

        File imageFile = new File(picturesDirectory, "picture" + timeStamp +".jpg");
        return imageFile;
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

<provider
            android:authorities="lmathurin.raptor.provider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="+"/>

</paths>
```

I followed this tutorial when writing out the code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jstmSgAK3Fo

I believe the code is failing in the `invokeCamera()` method as the app asks for camera permissions and then crashes

Here's the stacktrace:

```
05-05 18:23:02.099 7844-7844/lmathurin.raptor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: lmathurin.raptor, PID: 7844
                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picture20180505_182302.jpg
                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:712)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:401)
                                                                    at lmathurin.raptor.Test.invokeCamera(Test.java:85)
                                                                    at lmathurin.raptor.Test.dispatchTakePictureIntent(Test.java:65)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294) 
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: `app crashes` with a stacktrace in the logcat, which you have to provide immediately after writing the word `crashes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Hi lmthrn - good question but yes, you should always provide stack traces, error messages et cetera. Question answerers aren't psychic! Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks, will update with the stacktrace in a bit

Comment: I have added the stacktrace, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `file_paths.xml` instead of `+` put `.`, it basically means that it's a current directory.